# Combine css files

Tags: silverstripe

I'm using Silverstripe 3.0

I tried to combine all my css files into one file:

```
$themeFolder = 'themes/' . SSViewer::current_theme() . '';

$cssFiles = array(
    $themeFolder . '/css/reset.css',
    $themeFolder . '/css/typography.css',
    $themeFolder . '/css/jquery.fancybox.css',
    $themeFolder . '/css/form.css'        
);

array_walk($cssFiles,'Requirements::css');
Requirements::combine_files($themePath . 'css/core.css',$cssFiles);
Requirements::set_combined_files_folder('.');
Requirements::process_combined_files();
```

Unfortunately instead of having one file core.css which combines the others, I have still 4 css files. It seems that silverstripe has no permission to write my css files?

Any idea what is going wrong? Thank you

Comment: Are you in development mode? If so, SilverStripe will not combine files for ease of development.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem! Thank you

Comment: @ajshort may I suggest posting this as answer as well and let Steve accept it as correct answer to have this question marked as resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Even though this is answered in the comments, adding a real answer so this question doesn't appear in the unanswered list on SO)

@ajshort is spot on for why this would happen:

> Are you in development mode? If so, SilverStripe will not combine files for ease of development.

#### Technical Description

In the `Requirements_Backend` class which does the heavy lifting for the `Requirements` class, there is a line of code ([SS 3.0](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/source-class-Requirements.html#962) and [SS 3.1](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-Requirements.html#1060)) during the processing of combined files that affects whether it will combine or not.

Taken straight from the API docs:

```
if((Director::isDev() && !$runningTest && !isset($_REQUEST['combine'])) || !$this->combined_files_enabled) {
    return;
}
```

Basically if you are in dev-mode **and** `SaphireTest` is not running **and** that there is not a GET or POST variable set called "combine".

That means if you include a query parameter called "combine" (`?combine=false`), it will still combine the files while you are in dev-mode.